# beans.NotReadablePropertyException in spring security

Tags: spring-security

I am very new to spring security . I picked up [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847199747) book and trying to execute the code .

While I do this I am getting

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property
'principal.username' of bean class 
[org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken]: 
Bean property 'principal.username' is not readable or has an invalid getter 
method: 
Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

My spring-security xml config :

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.do" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login.do"/>
</http>


<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">

    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userService">
            <user authorities="ROLE_USER" name="guest" password="guest"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
    <!-- Ch 3 Change Password Service -->
    <!-- 
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService"/>
     -->
</authentication-manager>
```

Am I missing something ?

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Please provide your spring security XML configuration

Comment: I have edited my original post to add the pring security XML configuration.

Comment: Configuration is OK, as Stephen says please add the stacktrace

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What the error message seems to be indicating is that something is trying to access a non-existent property on an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` ; i.e. the authentication token that spring security uses when the session is not logged in.

I suspect that the problem is actually occurring either in your servlet code, or in a JSP that is trying to access the name of the current user via a spring security tag.

The complete stacktrace for the error might give us more clues.  At least it should tell us where the exception is coming from.

(For what it is worth, an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` does have a `principal` property, but that property is not normally an object that has a `username` property.  Indeed, it is often just a String.)

Comment: Ya. It is solved . Thank you . As you said ,the problem was in the jsp trying to access the name that does not exist .

Comment: Apologies for that! Please find this and any other minor errata on [the unofficial book web site](http://www.springsecuritybook.com) that I maintain myself. The mechanism of updating the code with the publisher to fix this is likely to cause more problems :( -- Peter (Author, _Spring Security 3_)

Answer (score 9):

I am reading/following the "Spring Security 3" book. Just add the following lines to the header.jsp  The problem is that principal.username does not exists if you are not logged in.

```
<div class="username">
    Welcome, 
    <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">  
        <strong><sec:authentication property="principal.username"/></strong>
    </sec:authorize>
</div>
```

Comment: `Marked answer` is the explanation, this is the code to solve ..+1.. :)

Comment: You didn't mention how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites as follows:

1. Add spring security taglib in jsp page you want to show username,

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
   ```
2. Add spring security jars, use

   ```
   <sec:authentication property="principal" />
   ```

   in jsp where you want to show the username

Following will show up:

1. **anonymousUser**, means user is not logged in
2. **string representation of object**, means user is logged in

But do not print string representation of object on page.

Here's a pseudo code:

```
if principal==anonymousUser
    show login button
else (do not use principal here too)
    show username with logout button
```